# How to use .replace() properly

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to remove "--" from words. For example, the word "World--fourthousand" should be replaced with white space doing string.replace('--', ' ')

String.replace('--', ' ') I have already tried and doesn't remove it.

```
if "--" in string:
        string.replace("--", " ")
```

Expected "World fourthousand"
Actual "World--fourthousand"

Answer (score 0):

replace returns a new string with the substring replaced, it doesn't alter the original string. So you could do:

```
string = string.replace("--"," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The replace() function should return a copy of the string with the intended characters replaced. That being said, I believe you should assign the result of the replace function into another variable, which will hold the desired value.

```
if "--" in string:
    new_string = string.replace("--", " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are what you call immutable objects, which means that whenever you modify them, you get a new object, and the original string is intact, so you would need to save the edited string in a new variable like so:

```
s = "World--fourthousand"
s = s.replace("--"," ")
print(s)
#World fourthousand
```

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.replace

> Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.